# add amount to subtotal by clicking checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How Can I convert the following into checkbox selection instead of dropdown count ?
means I would like to add value to subtotal just by selection each items.
If there is a simple way please share, I just want to get the result (subtotal) as plane text. the table is from an example I found online (http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/4hrx38nf/).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">Subtotal</span>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td><span>TOTAL</span></td>
            <!-- Fix: Moved the total field to the right place -->
            <td class="total">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adult</td>
            <td><span id="price" class="price">8.25</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">0</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Junior</td>
            <td><span id="price" class="price">6.75</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="qty">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">0</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senior</td>
            <td><span id="price" class="price">6.75</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="qty">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">0</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student</td>
            <td><span id="price" class="price">6.75</span> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="qty">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">0</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    update_amounts();
    // Fix: Invalid selector for the select fields
    $('select[name=qty]').change(update_amounts);
});

function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // Fix: price is in text, not in a form field
        // and it must be cleaned from the pound sign
        var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
        var amount = (qty * price);
        sum += amount;
        $(this).find('.subtotal').text('' + amount);
    });

    //just update the total to sum  
    $('.total').text('$' + sum);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version

Note I removed all IDs from the fields since they have to be unique.

If you want more than one checkbox, change

```
+$parent.find(".price").text()
```

to

```
$(this).val() * $parent.find(".price").text()
```

but then I would also suggest you change to radios instead

```js
const calc = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  $("[name=qty]").each(function() { // loop over ALL the checks
    const $parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    const val = $(this).is(":checked") ? +$parent.find(".price").text() : 0;
    $parent.find(".subtotal").text(`$${val}`);
    sum += val;
  })
  //just update the total to sum  
  $('.total').text(`$${sum}`);
};
$("#myTable").on("click", "[name=qty]", calc);
calc();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">Subtotal</span>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Adult</td>
      <td><span class="price">8.25</span></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td><span class="subtotal">0</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Junior</td>
      <td><span class="price">6.75</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1" /> </td>
      <td><span class="subtotal">0</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Senior</td>
      <td><span class="price">6.75</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td><span class="subtotal">0</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Student</td>
      <td><span class="price">6.75</span>
      </td>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td><span class="subtotal">0</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td><span>TOTAL</span></td>
      <!-- Fix: Moved the total field to the right place -->
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```